# Please explain the logic operation of the following cryptography equation

Tags: encryption, cryptography, logic

I have a question regarding the logic operations of the following equation. Can anyone explain what each operation does in this equation in a step by step process?

c=(m xor P(k,r),r)

The above equation is taken from this crypto problem.

Lets say P:{0,1}^n-->{0,1}^{n} is a pseudo-random permutation. 
Key generator (KG) generates a random string k. 
Encryption is based on input of key k and an n-bit string m, which returns the following: c = (m xor P(k,r),r), for some n-bit random string r.

Comment: This is much better suited for [crypto.se]. There is even support for LaTeX notation.

Answer (score 1):

The function uses a random value r and random key value k in the pseudorandom function.  The function converts a binary stream of length n into a new binary stream of the same length (in bits).  The output of this function is XORd with the message m.  The ciphertext function output is the result of the XOR I just mentioned and the value of r.

The person who wants to decrypt this needs r because they should already have k.  Using both, they can duplicate the pseudo random output of the function KG.  By XORing this with c, they obtain m again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I dont understand is how P(k,r) works. So P() is a pseudo-random permutation function? Is there a way to find out how it computes k,r? Also once it computes k,r you are left with c=(x,r) where x is the result of the (m xor p(k,r)). So is the cipher represented as x concatenated with r or is there some other operation that takes place?

Comment: Your first follow-up question confuses me. In your question you had the premise that P(k,r) is a PRP. My answer ran with that premise. Now you are asking me if P(k,r) is a PRP. I took you at your word it was. Assuming it is, there are many PRPs, so how it computes k,r depends on the PRP. If it is AES for example it seems reasonable that it would encrypt r using k as the secret key. For the final output, r can be concatenated or communicated in another way. It's not the same but consider that an RSA key is 2 values. Anyway Artjom B is right. You should post this question in Cryptography.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the help and quick reply. Ill see if I can find a way to transfer this over to cryptography section.